# Netbeans: create specialized "Insert code | Getters and Setters..." extension, with field selection

Tags: java, netbeans

In Netbeans 8.0, I've created an extension to the "Insert code" menu, as described in the [Code Generation Integration Tutorial](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-code-generator.html).  My extension generates special getters and setters for the current class.  However, much like the included "Insert code | Getters and Setters..." feature, I would like my extension to pop up the panel that shows the class and a list of fields, to allow the user to select which fields to generate methods for.

I've been unable to find any enhanced tutorials that discuss how to go about this; ideally, the component already used by Netbeans is exposed in the API and I could simply extend it, but searching through [this javadoc](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/) I've been unable to find it.

I cannot change the template for standard getters and setters, as I need this to be available for other classes during development.

Does anyone have any experience doing these kind of extensions, and can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this is not simple and you will need to check documentation and probably discuss it with other developers how to properly hook your extension. Post to one of NetBeans mailing lists where you can get answer from developers (https://netbeans.org/community/lists/index.html and use nbdev@netbeans.org or dev@platform.netbeans.org). Of course you can also check how similar functionality is implemented in NetBeans by looking at its source - http://wiki.netbeans.org/WorkingWithNetBeansSources